# Why won't the second pushed tile show?

Tags: python, tkinter

I placed the rectangles over the images. I then bound a click to a call that flipped tiles over by lowering the rectangle below the image. It works for the first call to the function, but when I click another tile, that one won't flip over. The program still registers the second flip because it'll flip everything back over if it's an incorrect match; the only problem is that it won't have the rectangle go under the image.

```
# ======================================= import statements
import tkinter as tk
import time
import random
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageTk as ImageTk

# ======================================= class def

class MemoryGame:

    def __init__(self):
        #initialize window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Sea Life Memory Game")
        self.window.minsize(590, 600)
        self.window.maxsize(590, 600)

        #set main canvas as background
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, bg="lightblue",
                                bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=590, height=600)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.chooseTile)

        #establish coordinates for tiles and shuffle image placement
        coordinates = [(5,30,105,130), (5,160,105,260), (5,290,105,390), (5,420,105,520), (125,30,225,130), (125,160,225,260), (125,290,225,390), (125,420,225,520), (245,30,345,130), (245,160,345,260), (245,290,345,390), (245,420,345,520), (365,30,465,130), (365,160,465,260), (365,290,465,390), (365,420,465,520), (485,30,585,130), (485,160,585,260), (485,290,585,390), (485,420,585,520)]
        imageChoices = ['cropped images/001-turtle.png','cropped images/007-blowfish.png','cropped images/010-jellyfish.png','cropped images/011-starfish.png','cropped images/018-lobster.png','cropped images/028-fish.png','cropped images/033-walrus.png','cropped images/042-goldfish.png','cropped images/045-seal.png','cropped images/046-penguin.png']
        random.shuffle(coordinates)

        #write title to top of canvas
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 15, text="Sea Life Memory Game!",
                                anchor="center", fill="white",
                                font="Times 24 bold")

        self.selectedTile = None

        #initialize counts
        coordinateCount = 0
        imageCount = 0
        self.imageCollection = {}
        #for loop to attach images to each rectangle on the canvas
        for i in range(len(imageChoices)):
            otherDict = {}
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates[coordinateCount]
            # if imageCount <= 9:
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imageChoices[imageCount]))
            self.image.img = self.image
            self.id = self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, anchor="nw",
                                    image=self.image.img)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", outline="white")
            coordinateCount += 1
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates[coordinateCount]
            self.id = self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, anchor="nw",
                                               image=self.image.img)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", outline="white")
            coordinateCount += 1
            imageCount += 1

            otherDict["faceDown"] = True
            self.imageCollection[self.id] = otherDict

        #create instructional text
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 550, text="Find all the pairs as fast as possible.",
                                fill="white", font="Times 18", anchor="center")
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 570, text="Click on a card to turn it over and find the same matching card.",
                                fill="white", font="Times 18", anchor="center")


    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    global list
    list = []
    def chooseTile(self, event):
        # global list
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        item = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5)
        list.append(item)
        print(len(list))
        if len(list) < 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(list[0][1])
        elif len(list) == 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(list[1][1])
            if self.canvas.itemcget(list[0][0], "image") == self.canvas.itemcget(list[1][0], "image"):
                list.clear()
            else:
                time.sleep(1.0)
                self.canvas.lower(list[0][0], list[0][1])
                self.canvas.lower(list[1][0], list[1][1])
                list.clear()







# ======================================= script calls

game = MemoryGame()
game.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the update will be performed after `chooseTile()` returns to tkinter `mainloop()`.  But the images are already reset to lower layer when the function returns, so you cannot see the second selected image.

The simple fix is calling `self.canvas.update_idletasks()` to force the update to show the second selected image before `time.sleep(1.0)`:

```py
    def chooseTile(self, event):
        # global list
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        item = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5)
        list.append(item)
        print(len(list))
        if len(list) < 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(list[0][1])
        elif len(list) == 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(list[1][1])
            if self.canvas.itemcget(list[0][0], "image") == self.canvas.itemcget(list[1][0], "image"):
                list.clear()
            else:
                # force the canvas to show the second selected image
                self.canvas.update_idletasks()
                time.sleep(1.0)
                self.canvas.lower(list[0][0], list[0][1])
                self.canvas.lower(list[1][0], list[1][1])
                list.clear()
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the correction, and it does show the second click, but only sometimes. It works fine after a few clicks and unsuccessful matches and then the tiles start to stop flipping over; I think this issue is somewhere within my conditionals

Comment: It works fine for me if the same image is not clicked twice.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work!!

```
# ======================================= import statements 
import tkinter as tk
import random
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageTk as ImageTk
# ======================================= class def

class MemoryGame:

    def __init__(self):
        #initialize window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Sea Life Memory Game")
        self.window.minsize(590, 600)
        self.window.maxsize(590, 600)

        #set main canvas as background
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, bg="lightblue",
                                bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width=590, height=600)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.chooseTile)

        #establish coordinates for tiles and shuffle image placement
        coordinates = [(5,30,105,130), (5,160,105,260), (5,290,105,390), (5,420,105,520), (125,30,225,130), (125,160,225,260), (125,290,225,390), (125,420,225,520), (245,30,345,130), (245,160,345,260), (245,290,345,390), (245,420,345,520), (365,30,465,130), (365,160,465,260), (365,290,465,390), (365,420,465,520), (485,30,585,130), (485,160,585,260), (485,290,585,390), (485,420,585,520)]
        imageChoices = ['cropped images/001-turtle.png','cropped images/007-blowfish.png','cropped images/010-jellyfish.png','cropped images/011-starfish.png','cropped images/018-lobster.png','cropped images/028-fish.png','cropped images/033-walrus.png','cropped images/042-goldfish.png','cropped images/045-seal.png','cropped images/046-penguin.png']
        random.shuffle(coordinates)

        #write title to top of canvas
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 15, text="Sea Life Memory Game!",
                                anchor="center", fill="white",
                                font="Times 24 bold")


        #initialize counts
        coordinateCount = 0
        imageCount = 0
        self.imageCollection = []
        #for loop to attach images to each rectangle on the canvas
        for i in range(len(imageChoices)):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates[coordinateCount]
            self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imageChoices[imageCount]))
            self.image.img = self.image
            self.id = self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, anchor="nw",
                                    image=self.image.img)
            self.imageCollection.append(self.id)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", outline="white")
            coordinateCount += 1
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordinates[coordinateCount]
            self.id = self.canvas.create_image(x1, y1, anchor="nw",
                                               image=self.image.img)
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="white", outline="white")
            coordinateCount += 1
            imageCount += 1

            self.imageCollection.append(self.id)

        #create instructional text
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 550, text="Find all the pairs as fast as possible.",
                                fill="white", font="Times 18", anchor="center")
        self.canvas.create_text(295, 570, text="Click on a card to turn it over and find the same matching card.",
                                fill="white", font="Times 18", anchor="center")


    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    global lst
    lst = []
    global matches
    matches = 0

    def chooseTile(self, event):
        global lst
        global matches
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        item = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x-1,y-1,x+1,y+1)
        lst.append(item)
        if len(lst) < 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(lst[0][1], lst[0][0])
        elif len(lst) == 2:
            self.canvas.tag_lower(lst[1][1],lst[1][0])
            if self.canvas.itemcget(lst[0][0], "image") == self.canvas.itemcget(lst[1][0], "image"):
                matches += 2
                lst.clear()
            else:
                self.window.update_idletasks()
                self.window.after(1500)
                self.canvas.lower(lst[0][0], lst[0][1])
                self.canvas.lower(lst[1][0], lst[1][1])
                lst.clear()
        if matches == 20:
            self.window.update_idletasks()
            self.window.after(1000)
            self.window.destroy()

# ======================================= script calls

game = MemoryGame()
game.window.mainloop()
```